# Java - Approaches to doing transactions on an object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a simple Java object (not connected to any database) and I would like to have transactional semantics on it. Here is a contrived example:

```
class MySession {
     public User user;
     public int numLogins;
}

public void login(MySession session, String user) {

    loginToDatabase(user);

    session.beginTransaction();
    try {

         session.user = user;

         sendLoginAcknowledgement(); //Throws some exception if failed

         session.numLogins++;

         session.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
         // Should reset session.user to the previous value
         session.rollback();
         return;
    }
}
```

What are my options for doing this in Java? Is JTA intended for this purpose? EJB? Is implementing a Memento pattern for the object the simplest option?

Comment: [Java Transaction API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) JTA/JTS should be the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain in which way the transaction can be compromised? Imho all different solutions to protect the transaction are based on concrete assumptions what can disturb it.

Comment: I updated the example, although I admit it is very contrived. I want to ensure that the object ends up in a consistent state. If sendLoginAcknowledgement() fails, the user variable is cahnged but not the numLogins variable

Comment: Transactions in the context of an ACID DB is a well defined concept: you have several queries interacting with the DB and if one fails, whatever happened before is rolled back. This is a complicated process which is managed by the DB itself. You seem to want something similar applied to your code: it performs several operations and if one fails you want to *cancel* the previous operations. But only *you* can define how that can be done. So I think that you will probably need to write the logic manually. Giving more info on what the operations are may be useful.

Comment: Is every transaction performed in a single thread, or it can be shared among several threads?

Comment: I awarded the bounty to the highest voted. In retrospect it was a silly question. In developing the application I found that in all cases I could group modifications to the object's state sequentially, and since it's simple getters and setters, no chance of exceptions in those objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid reinvent the wheel. You can do the following:

- Use a in memory Database like H2 or HSQLDB
- Define your classes (that need transaction behavior) as JPA Entities.
- Use JPA and configure persistence.xml for create the structure of database automatically from JPA Entities on application startup.
- If you are in a JEE environment you can use JTA and  Container Managed Transaction.  Otherwise you can use programmatically transactions

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Software Transactional Memory (STM). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory. In Java, Google returns this: http://multiverse.codehaus.org/60second.html, which seems to do what you want, but I haven't used it personally.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about POJOs on the heap -- not dealing with any external resources like databases -- the only way I can think of to do this is by keeping track of the tentative new state separately from the old state, then `commit` becomes an object assignment of current state.

In Java, object assignment is atomic so you don't have to worry about the object reference assignment failing halfway.  (Although, IIRC, 64-bit longs and double assignment is NOT atomic.)

Here's an example of a similar pattern in Javascript with KnockoutJS, to revert to original values:

http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html

Answer (score 0):

At a general level, you could apply the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (which is one of the "classic" [GoF patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four_(software))).

The approach is to remember every *command* performed on your object in a manner that's reversible/undoable, eg. have every operation implement an `Undo` interface and push the operations on the object onto a stack, along with a "current" copy of the object (so a stack element would contain the operation on the object (the command) and the object as it was changed by that command. This gives you full reversibility, which might be over the top, but should give an idea.

Once you `commit()` apply all ops on the stack to the underlying object, and in the `rollback()` situation, just clear the stack.

I hope this can help you a bit further along!

Cheers,